# I heard in a DhammaTalk, "You enjoy more, you finish your blessings quickly. "

Tags: sutras, rebirth

It is like if you leave a normal life and don't do evil. But still may end up in lower 3 realms if keep enjoying and finish your blessing.

What does this mean? Does a layperson have to not enjoy at all in terms of 5 Sensual Pleasures like travelling, music, movies, food ?
We don't know how much blessing we have and where we might be reborn. So please help out with this taking scenarios of a layperson and a monk in same situation.